# Realm Browser is working but not showing

Tags: realm

I'm fresher for realm.First time,i generate demo database and open it.But Realm Browser screen not show on desktop although still work.I work on osx 10.9.5 (virtual machine).

Please help me

Comment: It's unclear to me what you mean by "is working but not showing". You also write "screen not show on desktop although still work". What is it that "works"? Can you please elaborate your issue? Maybe add screenshoot.

Answer (score 1):

This was taken care of in the newest release, just download the newest realm browser from the website and install it.

Answer (score 0):

Following from @bmunks suggestion - here's some additional detail as I've encountered the same issue - on two different mac's (iMac/MBP) both running Mavericks with the latest 0.89.1 distro.  Steps to reproduce:

- start the realm browser
- Menu: Tools create demo database (successfully displays file window)
- create and then select open

.. result; no window opens.

I've had this issue before with another app and was able to resolve it by following some of the steps posted here: [superuser.com / move-an-off-screen-window-back-on-screen-on-mac-os-x](https://superuser.com/questions/55341/move-an-off-screen-window-back-on-screen-on-mac-os-x).

I have tried them all for this issue and no luck.  Here's an example of what I see when trying to get the Realm window visible

[image]

All I get is:
[image]

Comment: I've just been able to confirm that the app works fine on Yosemite

Comment: We just fixed the issue on Mavericks (see github: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/pull/1268). Thanks for reporting!